# Leak Suspects Report not getting rendered on Eclipse MAT

Tags: eclipse-mat

When I try to open leak suspects for my heap dump, a zip file gets created in the same location as that of the heap dump file. But, it doesn't get rendered on MAT (I'm using MAT version 1.7.0). I have separately unzipped the leak suspects zip file and opened the html file in it to view the leak suspects. Any ideas on how to make this automatically get rendered on MAT?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551971